# How create dataframe from downloaded htm file from SAP

Tags: python, html, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I need to create a data frame from this HTML file. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7b26.png)

I tried some codes with `beautifulSoup`, but it doesn't work. Also, I don't know how to create the data frame, because know only read_html, but the file is HTML

```
   table = BeautifulSoup(open('D:\DownloadingEmail\Job WSCZ_PO_STATUS_REPORT, Step 1.htm','r', encoding="utf8").read()).find_all()
df = pd.read_html(table)
```

And I've got TypeError: Cannot read object of type 'ResultSet'

Comment: first off, get rid of the `.find_all()`. Just read in the file, then (as long as there is `<table>` tags in the html/string, you can do `pd.read_html()`

Comment: I remove `.find_all()` and it writes TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: I send you the file. Thank you so much for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's quite a bit of problems with these 2 lines of code. First, you're trying to store the htm as a soup object, and then not really doing anything after that to parse the table.

Secondly, then you try to read the htm into pandas, but at that point it's not htm, it's beautifulSoup object.

You should be able to read in the html as string, then use pandas `.read_html()` to parse the table (Note: Pandas uses BeautifulSoup under the hood).

This will return a list of dataframes (all the `<table>` tags). I then just append all the of them together into 1 final dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

htmStr = open('D:\DownloadingEmail\Job WSCZ_PO_STATUS_REPORT, Step 1.htm','r', encoding="utf8").read()
list_of_dataframes = pd.read_html(htmStr)

df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```

**Output: First 5 rows of 943 total rows**

```
print (df.head(5).to_string())
0 Doc. Type Pur. Doc. Item        Material Stor. location Order Quantity GR Quantity Open Quantity Outbound DN Quantity PGI Quantity Incoterms1              Pur. Group Name  Vendor Document Date    ETA Date                     Remark                     Vendor Name Currency Unit Price Pur. Group(PO) Pur. Group(Material)      Pur. Group Name Your reference Our reference Shipping instructions: Descr.
1       ZUC  14439416   10      L15813-002           K131             10           0            10                   10           10        FCA  Juliet z zhu 祝慧君#1824 #1824    F040    2019/09/26  2019/11/17                        NaN  SMS Infocomm Global Service(CQ      USD   16.77000            76K                  76C         Lukas Zezula       Critical      Critical                        By AIR
2       ZUC  14439416   20      756743-001           K131             15           0            15                   15            0        FCA  Juliet z zhu 祝慧君#1824 #1824    F040    2019/09/26  2020/01/01                        NaN  SMS Infocomm Global Service(CQ      USD   16.00000            76K                  753  Sonia Chou 周曉婷#5510       Critical      Critical                        By AIR
3       ZUC  14439430   10    6026B0256601           K13R             20           0            20                    0            0        DAP                 Petr Studeny    F0B0    2019/09/26  2019/10/25        C1R7 SP BUFFER K137  Wistron InfoComm (Philippines)      USD    0.24179            76J                  NaN                  NaN           C1R7          C1R7                        By AIR
4       ZUC  14439435   10  074.02260.0A43           K13R             30           0            30                   30            0        DAP                 Petr Studeny    F603    2019/09/26  2019/10/26  C1R7 SHORTAGE URGENT K137             Wistron Corporation      USD    0.14834            76J                  NaN                  NaN           C1R7          C1R7                        By AIR
5       ZNB  14439467   10      826376-001           K131              2           0             2                    0            0        EXW  Juliet z zhu 祝慧君#1824 #1824  960125    2019/09/26  2019/09/30                        NaN             SMS(KUNSHAN)Co.,LTD      USD  110.30000            76K                  753  Sonia Chou 周曉婷#5510             CN      Critical                        By AIR
```